# Email address associated with your Salesforce account:

Tags: certification

I am trying to register at webassessor.com for taking Salesforce administration exam. I have a clarification on the question 'Email address associated with your Salesforce account:' - what should I provide here? I have my gmail associated with the trailblaze environment as part of trailheads and company email address for the Salesforce environnment associated with my actual work.

Also hope answers to last 3 are as below
Are you a: 'SFDC Partner'
Verification Opt-In: 'Yes'(I think its ok for others to view the certificate!)
Your role focuses primarily on which sector?: 'Private'

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use your personal email address (the trailhead one is fine). You don't want to get locked out of your webassessor account in case you leave your current company and no longer have access to your work email address.

If you work for a Salesforce Partner then you can put that you work for a SFDC Partner and also include the company name. This will associate your certifications with your company which helps the company meet partner level requirements.

Otherwise you can just leave it as Customer. And the rest of the options you selected are fine too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob! To clarify regarding the 'SFDC Partner' question - I work for 'A' Company in the Client 'B'  location for Salesforce projects. So what would be the best option to select?

Comment: If your company is a SFDC Partner, then you can select SFDC Partner. Otherwise it's ok to just leave it as Customer.

Comment: Thanks again. And I see that there is both options of either writing the exam in person or online. I think if its online, we should have webcam so that the invigilator can monitor us right? Are you aware of any issues with online test or suggest any preference among these two?

Comment: I prefer online just because I don't have to go somewhere to take the exam. I can take it from home where I'm more comfortable. Others prefer taking it onsite, so its just preference.

Comment: Here's more information about taking it online: http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Online-Proctoring-Completing-Your-Exam-Remotely

Comment: I am planning to take Salesforce Administrator exam. I have 4 years of work experience primarily as Salesforce QA with good  knowledge on basic Salesforce adminitration activites. I completed Salesforce Admin beginner trailhead as well and around 60% with intermediate. Do you think its sufficient to write the exam? I am not planning to go to any classroom training. Hope we get more questions from Admin beginner trail heads than intermediate? Any other references to prepare?

Comment: My advice is to go to the certification site and use the official study guide to prepare yourself for the topics that you should expect to see on the exam. Then go to help.salesforce.com and search for each topic. Then get yourself a free developer org and get hands on with each of those topics (trailhead probably had you do this). This is the best method, in my opinion, to prepare for the exams. Some people find the video courses on Udemy.com helpful. Those typically cost around $10 per course. Just search for "Salesforce Admin" and you will find them. Good luck on the exam!

Comment: If an UI related question comes, would that be related to lightning page for the exam?